# Multi-configuration Deployment Group Jobs with the Multipliers variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I'm trying to re-use a Deployment Group Job and execute it for each member of a ClientID list, but it is not working. The name of the stage will also be used in my tasks.

As described on this page...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

I've create two variables:
ClientID
client1, client2, client3

Multipliers
ClientID

The stage only has a Deployment Group Job and not an Agent Job because after the deploy I have tasks to run on the self-hosted servers. I need to stop and remove a service, copy files, register and restart a service.

There are no other options on the Stage or the Deployment Group Job for multipliers. (There is the "multiple" options for parallel deployments to servers within the group but that is unrelated as far as I know.)

If I add an Agent Job then I can see that it has the "Multi-configuration" and "Multipliers" options that other articles mention. On a deploy the agent job executes multiple times as expected but not the deployment group job.

The article above talks about "Multi-configuration deployments", so I'm I wrong to think the Deployment Group Job should work that way?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can't use multipliers in deployment groups, only on agent jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that using multipliers in the deployment groups is not feasible.

According to the definition of Multi-configuration in the agent job : each configuration will use a single agent.
But, in effect, a deployment group is just another grouping of agents, much like an agent pool.It could not assign a single agent to each configuration.
[image][image]

So I think that multipliers are not available in the deployment groups.If you want to use multipliers, then you need to use agent job.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this makes it useless for us for multi-tenant, on-premises deployments without a lot of pipeline duplication.